# Bash script with -e not terminated when using piped script and docker

Tags: bash, docker

The following `script.sh` is executed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

# code ...

su buser
mkdir /does/not/work
echo $?
echo This should not be printed
```

Output:

```
1
This should not be printed
```

How i execute the script:

```sh
docker exec -i fancy_container bash < script.sh
```

**Question:** Why does the script not terminate after the failing command even when `set -e` was defined and how can i get the script to exit on any failing command? I think the key point is the '<' operator, which i do not understand exactly *how* it executes the script.

**Notes:**

- `-e` means: Abort script at first error, when a command exits with non-zero status (except in until or while loops, if-tests, list constructs)

---

**Possible solution:**

```sh
docker exec -i fancy_container bash -c "cat > tmp.sh; bash tmp.sh" < script.sh
```

How it works:

1. `< script.sh` - Pipe all rows of this file from the **host**, to the `docker exec` command.
2. `cat > tmp.sh` - Save the incoming piped content to a file **inside** the container.
3. `bash tmp.sh` - Execute the file **as-whole** inside the container, which means `-e` works again as expected!

But i still don't know why the initial approach isn't working.

Comment: @ex1led That's what `-e` does (or should be doing): exit the script if an unguarded command has a non-zero exit status.

Comment: @chepner I thought that `-e` only works for pipelines in bash.

Comment: Grammatically speaking, a pipeline is just one or more commands separated by `|` or `|&`. `command -which -fails` is a pipeline of one command. (That is, confusingly, a pipeline does *not* necessarily contain a pipe.)

Comment: @ex1led The `-e` (should) works for all statements. As the definition is: _Abort script at first error, when a command exits with non-zero status (except in until or while loops, if-tests, list constructs)_ Expect if you do something like `crash-cmd || echo ignored`.

Comment: Welp, then I have no idea why the code script does not halt. ^^. Thanks  for the clarification!!

Comment: Does it abort properly if you just use `docker exec -i fancy_container bash -eu script.sh` or (assuming the script has its executable bit set) `docker exec -i fancy_container script.sh`?

Comment: Technically, it's `docker` whose standard input is set to `script.sh` (which `bash` inherits once it finally runs). I'm not sure if that's playing any role in this.

Comment: `set -e` is _extremely_ unreliable by nature. See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) going into detail on why it's better to pretend it doesn't exist, and do explicit error handling by hand.

Comment: Also relevant is https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, comparing how different shells implement different corner cases with `set -e` enabled. Do you _really_ expect someone to be able to memorize every detail of behavior for every possible shell to be able to read and understand the behavior of code with this (mis)feature active?

Comment: ...that said, to identify _which_ of the many corner cases is involved -- @FireEmerald, could I ask you to provide a [mre] someone else can run without changes or additions (like needing to have your specific Dockerfile) to see the problem themselves? An online sandbox like https://ideone.com/ or https://repl.it/ could serve the purpose as well. `set -e` behavior changes quite a bit between not just shells but also shell releases -- if we don't know which specific version of bash is in use we may not be able to repro, depending on exactly what is going on; having a sandbox fixes that.

Comment: (re: BashFAQ #105, by the way -- don't get sidetracked by the parable; the important part is the exercises section below).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Your comment pushed me in the right direction, the real `script.sh` contained a line `su --preserve-environment postgres`, which was the root cause of my issue as the `-e` option is cleared after using `su`.